# What does youtube xml data means?

Tags: xml, api, youtube-api

i have a question

i use java spring 2.5 to retrieve youtube xml data

so what is the meaning of

```
 media:content url='rtsp://r5---sn-o097zuez.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlF_ajFptwzChMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp'
```

and

```
/r5---sn-o097zuez.c.youtube.com ?
```

here is two xml data

```
rtsp://r11---sn-5hn7snlz.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlF_ajFptwzChMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp

rtsp://r5---sn-o097zuez.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlF_ajFptwzChMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

if xml data url are diffrent(middle of address ex; r5---sn-o097zuez.c.youtube.com) (but the end part is the same), can i play youtube video?

Comment: possible duplicate of [i wonder about youtube api url xml information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218264/i-wonder-about-youtube-api-url-xml-information)

Comment: If you want to improve a question, make changes, include answers to questions people have asked in the comments, please use the edit link on that question. Don't just open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rtsp:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTSP)//r5---sn-o097zuez.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlF_ajFptwzChMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp

is the [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) for the video, just as

[http:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)//stackoverflow.com/questions/19220585/what-mean-is-youtube-xml-data-plz-help-me

is the URL for this question.